# Get Bouncy Content Filter to run automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this awesome bouncy filter from [Codyhouse](https://codyhouse.co/gem/bouncy-content-filter/) but i can't for the life of me figure out how to make it run automatically i.e flip on its own and still accept user click events. The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/i_heart_php/bw1uff76/)...Thanks.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //wrap each one of your filter in a .cd-gallery-container
  bouncy_filter($('.cd-gallery-container'));

  function bouncy_filter($container) {
    $container.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var filter_list_container = $this.children('.cd-filter'),
        filter_values = filter_list_container.find('li:not(.placeholder) a'),
        filter_list_placeholder = filter_list_container.find('.placeholder a'),
        filter_list_placeholder_text = filter_list_placeholder.text(),
        filter_list_placeholder_default_value = 'Select',
        gallery_item_wrapper = $this.children('.cd-gallery').find('.cd-item-wrapper');

      //store gallery items
      var gallery_elements = {};
      filter_values.each(function() {
        var filter_type = $(this).data('type');
        gallery_elements[filter_type] = gallery_item_wrapper.find('li[data-type="' + filter_type + '"]');
      });

      //detect click event
      filter_list_container.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //detect which filter item was selected
        var selected_filter = $(event.target).data('type');

        //check if user has clicked the placeholder item (for mobile version)
        if ($(event.target).is(filter_list_placeholder) || $(event.target).is(filter_list_container)) {

          (filter_list_placeholder_default_value == filter_list_placeholder.text()) ? filter_list_placeholder.text(filter_list_placeholder_text): filter_list_placeholder.text(filter_list_placeholder_default_value);
          filter_list_container.toggleClass('is-open');

          //check if user has clicked a filter already selected 
        } else if (filter_list_placeholder.data('type') == selected_filter) {

          filter_list_placeholder.text($(event.target).text());
          filter_list_container.removeClass('is-open');

        } else {
          //close the dropdown (mobile version) and change placeholder text/data-type value
          filter_list_container.removeClass('is-open');
          filter_list_placeholder.text($(event.target).text()).data('type', selected_filter);
          filter_list_placeholder_text = $(event.target).text();

          //add class selected to the selected filter item
          filter_values.removeClass('selected');
          $(event.target).addClass('selected');

          //give higher z-index to the gallery items selected by the filter
          show_selected_items(gallery_elements[selected_filter]);

          //rotate each item-wrapper of the gallery
          //at the end of the animation hide the not-selected items in the gallery amd rotate back the item-wrappers

          // fallback added for IE9
          var is_explorer_9 = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 9') > -1;

          if (is_explorer_9) {
            hide_not_selected_items(gallery_elements, selected_filter);
            gallery_item_wrapper.removeClass('is-switched');
          } else {
            gallery_item_wrapper.addClass('is-switched').eq(0).one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function() {
              hide_not_selected_items(gallery_elements, selected_filter);
              gallery_item_wrapper.removeClass('is-switched');
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
});

function show_selected_items(selected_elements) {
  selected_elements.addClass('is-selected');
}

function hide_not_selected_items(gallery_containers, filter) {
  $.each(gallery_containers, function(key, value) {
    if (key != filter) {
      $(this).removeClass('is-visible is-selected').addClass('is-hidden');

    } else {
      $(this).addClass('is-visible').removeClass('is-hidden is-selected');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by "make it run automatically" you're talking about triggering the content-selection animation programatically, rather than requiring a user click. One possible solution is to assign an `id` to the selection elements, and then register the `click` handler directly to those elements, rather than the parent `filter_list_container`. Then, you can use jQuery's `trigger()` method to simulate a click on the appropriate element.

Assign an id in the html like this:

```
<a id="green" href="#0">Green</a>
```

Then register the click handler like this:

```
$("#red, #green, #blue").on('click', function(event){ ... }
```

...and trigger like this:

```
$("#green").trigger("click");
```

[Here's a JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7dvcb83/) with an example.

Comment: perfect, i only changed the time